# prior based image segmentation

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a problem at hand, in which my image is composed of strange objects which do not necessarily have closed contours. (more like rivers and channels on a plain back ground).

I am also provided with a set of prior images of the same size from different rivers that their general orientation and structure matches my river under study while their position in the image might deviate.

I am looking for an image segmentation method, (theory or practice, i am really looking for clues to start with) which can actually use my set of prior examples in segmenting my river. in my case there could be multiple rivers of the same general orientation present in the image.

I am also very interested in ways of statistically representing these complex structures. for example, if it was not a river image (binary image), and i knew it had a Gaussian structure, then I could use information in the covariance estimated by the examples. but in binary or trinary images, I can not.

Comment: Let's start with [Local Color Histogram](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/research/techreports/tr06-010.pdf), so that you can post some preliminary results on Stackoverflow, in order to help prospective answerers understand the type of difficulties that occur in this project. In general, you must show a lot of work (code, sample images, technical difficulties, etc.) in order to ask a question on Stackoverflow that answerers will want to look at.

Comment: Please give some examples of the priolr images that you have. Also provide the same for the input images where you want to do the search.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline for image segmentation

Sample a small region (possible a rectangle) inside the river, the assumption is that they will belong to the foreground and provide a good estimate about its color distribution. You should have an algorithm which can find a small region inside the river with high confidence, probably this algorithm can be trained on the data you have.

Since you know little about the background, it would to be ideal to chose pixels lying on the image frame as background pixels.

The idea is to use these pre-selected foreground and background pixels as seeds in a graph cut algorithm for segmentation. Selecting seeds is the most important part of a graph cut algorithm for segmentation, once you have good seeds, the segmentation would be more or less correct. There is plenty of literature/code available online on how to do segmentation using graph cuts.